# Auth::user() returns Null even if a user is logged in

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

Here inside store method data of newly registered user are saved in database and then new user is logged in.

After user authentication inside store method the controller will trigger the show method and inside the show method dd(Auth::user()) returns null null. I have my routes and controllers in Route middleware group. It means I have no logged in user.

How I can solve this?

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
    $data = $request->all();
    print_r($data);
    $rules = array(
       'username'  => 'unique:users,username|required|alpha_num',
       'password'  => 'required|alpha_num',
       'full_name' => 'required',
       'email'     => 'required|unique:users,email'
    );

    // Create a new validator instance.
    $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);
    if ($validator->fails()) {

        $errors = $validator->messages();
        return Redirect::route('user.create')->withErrors($validator);

    } else {

        $user = new User();
        $user->username = $request->username;
        $user->password = Hash::make($request->password);
        $user->full_name = $request->full_name;
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->joined = date('d-m-y H-i-s');
        $user->save();


        if(Auth::attempt(['username' => $request['username'],'password' => $request['password']])){
            return redirect()->route('user.show',[$request['username']]);
        }
    }
}

public function show($user)
{

    $indicator = is_numeric($user)?'user_id':'username';
    $info=User::where($indicator,'=',$user)->get()->first();
    if($info){

       dd(Auth::user());  // returns null
       $data = array('info' => $info);
       return View::make('user.show')->with('info',$data);
    }else{
         echo "this user doesn't exist";

         $info = User::where($indicator,'=', Auth::user()->$indicator)->first();
         $data = array('info' => $info);
         return View::make('user.show')->with('info',$data);
    }
}
```

my user model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
class User extends Model implements Authenticatable
{

    use \Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
    protected $table = 'users';
    public $timestamps = false;

}
```

Comment: You using default authentication or you have edited manually ?

Comment: added my user model to my question ..plz check..thats how i am using authentication...nothing manual

Comment: If you use laravel 5.2 you must have to web guard group in routes all url. Because Session middleware in "web" middleware.

Comment: Hey try in your store method `dd(Auth::user());` will you get out put or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the last `if` of your store function and after saving the $user add `Auth::login($user);`

```
     $user->save();

     Auth::login($user);

//In case of adding a new user, Even the below If is not necessary 
     if(Auth::attempt(['username'=>$request['username'],'password'=>$request['password'    ]])){


        return redirect()->route('user.show',[$request['username']]);
    }
```

Now the `Auth::user()` will always return `$user`

Comment: why i have to use auth login after auth::attempt..doesn't auth::attempt not log in user automatically?

Comment: @AL-zami I edited my answer. What u've done is kinda strange! Once you add a new to DB you don't need to check Auth::attempt()! Auth::attempt is used for login not signing up a user. so after a saving just  Auth::login($user); will be okay